# IDE for php prado

Tags: php, prado

iam looking for IDE with intellisense support for PHP Prado.

please suggest me some ide's.

-------**My Answer**----------------

None of the answers solved my problem, so carried on my research and **found one ide phpedit**

http://www.waterproof.fr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> iam looking for IDE with intellisense support for PHP Prado.

Well, I'm a Netbeans user, and use multiple frameworks. If you use a framework and make sure that it's in your include-path, Netbeans will automatically index the framework, and provide intellisense for it. I don't think you need an IDE with framework specific intellisense, I think you need an IDE that can do intellisense on existing frameworks :)

Comment: http://www.waterproof.fr/, solved my problem, marking you as answer as you have typed most.

Answer (score 0):

How about Netbeans alfa version of Prado support : 
http://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/the_first_alpha_version_of

**or** you can try default Prado support for such editors as Notepad++, Dreamweaver, InType or Textmate:

http://www.pradosoft.com/download/

Section : "PRADO Tools"

**or** you can check this Prado Forum out :

[IDE/Editor for Prado](http://www.pradoframework.com/forum/index.php?PHPSESSID=314d8cdo12b5nmeauphk4kgcf4&board=12.0)

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse-Prado plugin is ready. Please use it and suggest if you have any idea. It is and will remain open source, available at sourceforge

Answer (score 0):

i use sublime text 2 with autocomplete, look at this thread:[Link](https://code.google.com/p/prado3/downloads/list)